# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 when adding firebase_messaging

Tags: android, flutter, androidx

I have build a simple chat app, it all works fine, I have migrated it to Androidx. When I add firebase_messaging to my dependancies I get :- Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have the following currently in my Dependencies, and everything works great.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^5.0.5
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  page_transition: ^1.1.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+6
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+8
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.7
  animated_text_kit: ^1.3.1
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  flutter_form_builder: ^3.2.8
  geolocator: ^5.0.1
  toast: ^0.1.5
```

I am trying to add :-

```
firebase_messaging: ^5.1.4
```

when I run the app I get
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

sorted it, I changed
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
to 
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

now working fine